# Can't access object values using keys in Typescript (TS )

Tags: typescript, object, types

I have a simple object like so:

```
export const daysOfTheWeek = {
  0: "Sunday",
  1: "Monday",
  2: "Tuesday",
  3: "Wednesday",
  4: "Thursday",
  5: "Friday",
  6: "Saturday",
};
```

I'm trying to access it by using a variable like so:

```
const checkDay = (dayIndex: number):void => {
  console.log(daysOfTheWeek[dayIndex]) // error happens here
};
```

I'm expecting to log `"Sunday"`, however I get this error that keeps popping up:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; 4: string; 5: string; 6: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; 4: string; 5: string; 6: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell TypeScript that the `dayIndex: number` is not actually just a number, but one of the `daysOfTheWeek` keys.

```
const checkDay = (dayIndex: keyof typeof daysOfTheWeek):void => {
  console.log(daysOfTheWeek[dayIndex])
};
```

If you can't do that, then you'll have to narrow inside the function

```
const checkDay = (dayIndex: number):void => {
  if (dayIndex !== 1 && dayIndex !== 2 ...) {
    throw new Error('Not a day of the week');
  }
  console.log(daysOfTheWeek[dayIndex])
};
```

or assert it after checking ranges:

```
const checkDay = (dayIndex: number):void => {
  if (!Number.isInteger(dayIndex) || dayIndex < 0 || dayIndex > 6) {
    throw new Error('Not a day of the week');
  }
  console.log(daysOfTheWeek[dayIndex as keyof typeof daysOfTheWeek])
};
```

Comment: Great, I went with the third option of asserting it as dayIndex has to be a number.